# How to merge similar date in HTML using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataframe in R which looks like.

```
Order Date   Sell       Sell_pc   Order_fm  mkt_pc    Dealer_pc
2020-01-01   5          14.34     340       11.23     23.43
2020-01-01   1000       14.34     45900     13.23     34.45
2020-01-02   12         12.33     13        15.44     23.66
2020-01-02   13000      11.45     600000    15.21     14.44
2020-01-03   110000     12.33     31        15.34     12.34
2020-01-03   1600       11.45     18000     13.31     24.45
```

I want to convert the above-mentioned data frame in HTML image in R, Where I want to merge to similar date in on in the same sequence and add a light gray column for every two-column skipping next two-column.

Required output like:

[image]

I have tried:

```
html_image<-df %>% tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
                                widths = rep(100, 6),
                                caption = "Order Book Reported") %>%
  add_css_caption(css = list(c("font-weight", "border","font-size"),
                             c("bold", "1px solid black","16px")))%>% 
  add_css_row(css = list(c("background-color"), c("lightgray")), rows = 0:2)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the gt package, but your idea is an open issue on that project. Keep an eye on it though... https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/577

Comment: It looks like flextable can do it. There's an example here... https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/vignettes/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

The `gt`-package could be helpful here:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) |>
  group_by(Date) |>
  gt() |>
  # gt(rowname_col = "Date") |>
  tab_stubhead(label = "Date") |>
  tab_header(
    title = md("Order Book Reported")
  ) |>
  tab_options(
    row_group.as_column = F,
    row_group.background.color = "gray",
    heading.background.color = "orange",
    column_labels.background.color = "orange"
  ) |>
  tab_options(row_group.as_column = TRUE) |>
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "grey")
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      rows = Date == "2020-01-02"
    )
  )
```

[image]